# pgr_createtoplogy -invalid geometry

Tags: pgrouting

When I'm working on my routing, I wanted to make a topology and this error occur
saying:

> Unexpected error parse error - invalid geometry

this is my code

```
select pgr_createTopology('table_name',0.001,'the_geom','gid');
```

my RSID is - espg 5234

this is my geometry column with table[image: this is my table what should i do]

Answer (score 0):

What is your geometry type run ST_GeometryType(the_geom) if you are not sure.
CreateTopology expects 2D LINESTRING.